# PHP Contact Form validation on submit

Tags: php, html, contact-form

So the deal is this: the validation process starts after the user hits submit. However for some reason the code is not working.

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['submitted']) {
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
    else //email is valid
    {
        //validate presence of name and message
        if (empty($name) || empty($message)) {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        } else //ready to go!
        {
            $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
            if ($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
            else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
        }
    }
} else {
    $response = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="contact" method="post">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Company" name="message_company" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_company']); ?>">
                        <textarea name="message_text" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="contact-button" name="submitted">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <?php echo $response ?>
```

EDIT:
Sorry I forgot to add the last part of my post, what I ment was the PHP script should work the moment I hit the submit buttom. But the if ($_POST['submitted']) {} doesn't get triggered by my submit button. I was wondering why that is?

Comment: '*the code is not working*' - Is not really helpful. Have you check your logs? Is error reporting enabled? Are any errors showing?

Comment: "the code is not working" — What does that mean? Provide a clear problem statement. What, precisely isn't working? Does the `if` stament at the top fail when you expect it to pass? Do you not see the email you expect in your inbox? Narrow down the problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the last part of my post, what I ment was the PHP script should work the moment I hit the submit buttom. But the if ($_POST['submitted']) {} doesn't get triggered by my submit button. I was wondering why that is?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you aren't assigning your variables to POST elements.

If you replace `$email` with `$_POST['message_email']`, `$name` with `$_POST['message_name']`, `$message` with `$_POST['message_text']` in your first snippet you may find better luck.

Regardless, I can see quite a few unused variables in this snippet including `$headers`, `$to`, `$subject`, and every reporting variable used under `my_contact_form_generate_*`. Make sure these are also set.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, this is merely a snippet of my PHP code. I just wondering why my Submit button isn't triggering the if ($_POST['submitted']) {}

Comment: No worries. This looks like WordPress to me - what file are the snippets under? What is the permalink generated by `the_permalink()`? It may be that your snippets are on different pages and thus one isn't being loaded by the other. Can you drop a `if (is_array($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) print_r($_POST);` somewhere just before or after your first snippet so you can see the contents of $_POST? (You may need to right click -> view page source to see it!)

Comment: Have you also tried adding a `value='Submit!'` to your `<input type="submit">`? It could very well be that it **is** posting, just that we're checking `if ($_POST['submitted'])` vs something like `if (isset($_POST['submitted']))`.

Comment: Ah that was the solution! Thanks I oversaw that little part.